# can't stop or start mysql on fedora 17

Tags: fedora, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have recently setup a fedora 17 machine with Gnome and installed Mysql using the add/remove software GUi included. Mysql seems to be working - I can login, select databases, do queries etc but if I try to stop/start or get the status of the service in a teminal I get this:

```
#service mysql stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  mysql.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
[root]#service mysql start 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.

[root]# service mysql status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysql.service
mysql.service
      Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
      Active: inactive (dead)
```

Why? 
I'm trying to get Mysql workbench working.....

Answer (score 1):

If mysql was installed successfully, it should start with:

```
service mysqld start
```

The error message is confusing as it doesn't explicitly tell that you typed it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The following should show you if you have the service installed:

`systemctl status mysqld.service`

(try "yum install mysql" if not.)

That will also tell you if it's enabled.  If not:

`systemctl enable mysqld.service`

That enables starting on reboot.  (You don't HAVE to do that.)

`systemctl start mysqld.service`

will start it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the service's name is mysqld, not mysql!

so all commands just need one mode character

examples:

> service mysqld start
>
> systemctl start mysqld
>
> chconfig mysqld on
>
> systemctl enable mysqld

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, MySQL is replaced with its fork MariaDB

so following commands will probabily work on CentOS 7 and other same versions:

> systemctl stop mariadb.service                //Stop MySQL Service
>
> systemctl start mariadb.service                //Start MySQL Service
>
> systemctl restart mariadb.service                //Restart MySQL
> Service

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 7.2. This answer should be kept kere for those users, since RPM-based distros such as Fedora are similar and Google directs search results for CentOS here.